# Team/Group's MailNickname - allowed characters or regex

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I'm looking for an exact set of allowed characters for the `mailNickname` when creating a new Group/Team.

I found some documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/set-unifiedgroup?view=exchange-ps#parameters which describes Exchange's `Alias` but, when creating a Team with displayName `Tést`, for example, the `é` is removed from the mailNickname - so this doesn't seem to map 100%.

So, my question is: is there a concrete list of characters, or a Regex we can use, to validate a mailNickname locally?

Currently I use this one, but it doesn't seem to be completely correct:

```
^(?!\.)(?!.*\.$)(?!.*?\.\.)[a-zA-Z0-9\u00A1-\u00FF!#$%&'*+\-/=?^_`{}|~.]+$
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [create group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-groups?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request-body) documentation, the mailNickname cannot include the following characters:
`@()\[]";:.<>,SPACE`
[image: MailNickName excluded]

Comment: There seem to be a whole lot of other characters which are not supported though. é è á ò, for example, and a whole lot of symbol characters. I’m really looking for a full list of these... not sure if such a list exists publicly though. :)

Comment: Hi @Nsevens, those are not exist in document, if you feel it should be there in the document then could you please raise [user voice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/).

Comment: @Jagadeesh-MSFT thanks. But ... wasn't user voice being decomissioned as a MS feedback platform?

Comment: Seems like the documentation was updated and now reads: "This property can contain only characters in the ASCII character set 0 - 127 except the following: @ () \ [] " ; : . <> , SPACE."